# PHP - Disparar outro script dentro de um script sem abortar o atual

Tags: php

Tenho um script em PHP no qual necessito "**simplesmente disparar**" outro script porém, sem perder o fluxo do atual script.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
// um comando
// outro comando
//*** Aqui preciso, por exemplo, disparar o script: teste.php

// outro comando
// outro comando
// outro comando
//*** Aqui preciso novamente disparar o script: teste.php

// outro comando
// outro comando
// outro comando
// outro comando
// fim

(OBS: Servidor compartilhado Locaweb)
?>
```

Comment: Use `include` ou `require` par ter certeza de que vai disparar uma vez só use `_once` exemplo: `include_once`

Comment: Não pode ser utilizado include ou require.
A ideia é "disparar" um script em paralelo e não incluí-lo no script atual.

Comment: Inclua esta informação na pergunta então, e todos os outros detalhes relevantes (por exemplo, qual seu conceito de "disparar um script"), senão o pessoal pode perder tempo respondendo coisas que não vão te servir.

Comment: Na realidade, estou rodando um script que executa uma lista grande de tarefas. O intuito é, no final de cada tarefa, atualizar um diálogo com informações escritas sobre o andamento (se cada etapa foi bem-sucedida ou não). Essas informações sobre o progresso, traz para o usuário, informações precisas sobre aquilo que está acontecendo (ao invés de, apenas um gauge mostrando o percentual da execução).

Comment: Os colegas precisam prestar mais atenção quando uma pergunta é ESPECÍFICA ou CONCEITUAL.
Exemplos:

1) É possível abrir um arquivo texto em PHP?
(esta é uma pergunta CONCEITUAL (não necessita de nenhum código fonte) -> Basta fornecer alguns links ou fragmentos de códigos.

2) Meu botão submit não está funcionando, o que devo fazer?
(esta é uma pergunta específica e necessita que o usuário mostre seu código fonte)

Comment: É necessário, antes de tudo, que a pergunta seja lida com atenção.
Na minha pergunta, nem precisaria mostrar um pseudo-código, pois é uma pergunta CONCEITUAL.

Comment: Sim. Mas dizer que você quer executar outro script *em paralelo* é essencial. Seria bom também esclarecer o que quis dizer com "em paralelo" no comentário.

Comment: Eu mencionei isso no  código:

//*** Aqui preciso novamente disparar o script: teste.php

Basta ler.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver rodando este script no modo CGI(* A locaweb só permite a execução destes métodos em modo CGI), você pode usar a função exec do php

Não achei nada na locaweb sobre a função exec, mas encontrei sobre a função shell_exec que serve para executar comandos na shell:

http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_utilizar_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_PHP_shell_exec()

Não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer mas vale uma ressalva se sua idéia for realizar processamento em paralelo.

O PHP suporta threads, então se a sua idéia é essa dá uma olhada na doc:

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Outra opção se isso rodar na linha de comando e for síncrono, você pode subdividir este seu script em script menores e usar redirecionamento via pipes:

ex: script1.php, script2.php, script3.php

Rodaria na linha de comando algo como isso aqui:

php script1.php | php script2.php | php script3.php

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado user1030302 pela resposta. Vejo que você compreendeu bem a minha pergunta (que é conceitual), de formas que, não preciso colocar nenhum código fonte específico além daquele que exibi no início do post.